# Does an MVC 4 partial view use its parent view's .css and .js, or do you have to add the .css and .js into the partial view?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views

To clarify my question, say for example that I have a regular view with the following links to the following .js and .css files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/chosen.css" />
```

Now, let's say that I create a partial view that can be called from this regular view. Would I have to place the same links to the .js and .css files in the partial view, or does the partial view already use those files since they're being used in the regular view already? Also, how would this work if I have a layout with those .js and .css links to be used by all regular views. How does the parenting structure work in MVC4, or is there even a parenting structure?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the partial view is rendered into the main page.  Thus, the browser will pick up and use the JS and CSS that you already have declared in place.

The only caveat to this is if you load a partial view via AJAX.  If you have any javascript handlers, they will need to be initialized after the partial view is loaded, else your framework (jQuery for instance) will not have the event tied to the element.

Clarification on the above

**My partial view**

```
<div>
 <span id="clickMe">Click Me</span>
</div>
```

Here, you would need to attach the handler to the "clickMe" span after you load your partial view or declare the handler in the partial view such as

**My partial view round 2**

```
<div>
 <span id="clickMe">Click Me</span>
</div>
<script type="text\javascript">
   $(function(){
        $("#clickMe").on("click", function(){
            alert("He he, that tickles");
        });
   });
</script>
```